# Trying to clone private git repository, not asked for uid/pwd, get "core" file

Tags: git, clone

I have a private git repository on Github which I am trying to clone. I use `git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git`. It does not ask for username and password and there is no error. All I get is a file named `core` that has nothing to do with my repo.

Comment: What are the `stdout` to the terminal when you run `git clone`?

Comment: `Cloning into 'repository'...` then done.

Comment: What version of Git are you using? There's a bug in some older Git versions where if `getpwuid(getuid())` returns NULL, Git crashes unless you've set `core.user`,

Comment: 1.9.4, I'm ssh'ing to a university server. I'll try to set `core.user` and see if that helps.

Comment: I set core.user, still same problem.

Comment: 1.9.4 isn't in the buggy set (I think), and in any case, that obviously didn't work. But 1.9.4 is quite out of date—modern Git is 2.19. See if there's a newer one available for your system.

Comment: As this is a university server, I dont have root privilage.